# Pulling information at CONNECT BY PRIOR

Tags: sql, plsql

I have table with hierarchical structure (n,n_parent,data):

for example:

- Directory 1 (1,0,null)

  - Subdirectory 1 (44,1,null)

    - Item 1 (83,44,a)
    - Item 2 (98,44,b)
  - Subdirectory 2 (46,1,null)

    - Item 1 (8,46,c)
    - Item 2 (9,46,d)
- Directory 2 (4,0,null)

  - Subdirectory 1 (54,4,null)

    - Item 1 (43,54,e)
    - Item 2 (48,54,f)
  - Subdirectory 2 (101,4,null)

    - Item 1 (19,101,g)
    - Item 2 (314,101,h)

if i have id, i build item with this id and it's parents:
for example i have id: 83, 98, 48, 9:

`SELECT distinct name, n, n_parent FROM portalmdo.zre_filter a START WITH N in (83, 98, 48, 9) CONNECT BY PRIOR N_PARENT = N`

```
Directory 1 (1,0,null)    
Subdirectory 1 (44,1,null)  
Item 1 (83,44,a)  
Item 2 (98,44,b)    
Subdirectory 2 (46,1,null)    
Item 2 (9,46,d)    
Directory 2 (4,0,null)    
Subdirectory 1 (54,4,null)    
Item 2 (48,54,f)
```

(the order is not important issue)

I want that field data is transmitted to parents:
for example:

```
Directory 1 (1,0,a)    
Subdirectory 1 (44,1,a)  
Item 1 (83,44,a)  
Directory 1 (1,0,b)    
Subdirectory 1 (44,1,b) 
Item 2 (98,44,b)    
Directory 1 (1,0,d)  
Subdirectory 2 (46,1,d)    
Item 2 (9,46,d)    
Directory 2 (4,0,f)    
Subdirectory 1 (54,4,f)    
Item 2 (48,54,f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CONNECT_BY_ROOT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators004.htm#SQLRF0031) (10g+):

```
SQL> WITH data AS (
  2     SELECT 'Directory 1' name, 1 n,0 n_p,null dat FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 'Subdirectory 1', 44,1,null FROM DUAL
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 1', 83,44,'a' FROM DUAL
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 2', 98,44,'b' FROM DUAL
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 'Subdirectory 2', 46,1,null FROM DUAL
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 1', 8,46,'c' FROM DUAL
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 2', 9,46,'d' FROM DUAL
  9     UNION ALL SELECT 'Directory 2', 4,0,null FROM DUAL
 10     UNION ALL SELECT 'Subdirectory 1', 54,4,null FROM DUAL
 11     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 1', 43,54,'e' FROM DUAL
 12     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 2', 48,54,'f' FROM DUAL
 13     UNION ALL SELECT 'Subdirectory 2', 101,4,null FROM DUAL
 14     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 1', 19,101,'g' FROM DUAL
 15     UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 2', 314,101,'h' FROM DUAL
 16  )
 17  SELECT DISTINCT name, n, n_p, connect_by_root(dat) dat
 18    FROM data a
 19  START WITH N IN (83, 98, 48, 9)
 20  CONNECT BY PRIOR N_P = N;

NAME                    N    N_P DAT
---------------------- -- ------ -------
Item 2                 48     54 f
Item 1                 83     44 a
Item 2                 98     44 b
Subdirectory 1         44      1 b
Subdirectory 1         44      1 a
Item 2                  9     46 d
Directory 1             1      0 b
Subdirectory 2         46      1 d
Directory 1             1      0 d
Directory 2             4      0 f
Subdirectory 1         54      4 f
Directory 1             1      0 a
```